# Can't append Element/Component to a Extjs Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to append a button to a panel. First I create the panel, and render it to **Ext.getBody()**. That seems to work fine, but then I want to render a button to that panel, and it gives this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null

Here is the code :

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    var p = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
        renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
        html:'myPanel'
    })


    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Click me!!!!',
        renderTo: p,
        handler: function() {
            alert('You clicked the button!')
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle here :

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/694

Comment: BTW I am very new to extJS

Comment: check [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/696)

Comment: @MMT: You won't need the `renderTo` config anymore in that case, it just happens to work because `p` is `undefined` at the time.

Comment: @matt yes you are right, i just copied it from previous fiddle, updated it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand the difference between components and elements here.

A component is an instance of `Ext.Component` or one of its subclasses. An element refers to the DOM.

In your case, the [`renderTo`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-renderTo) configuration expects an element, but you're passing a component to it.

When nesting components you will typically use containers.

As `Ext.Panel` is a container all you need to do is add your button to it. You can either do that by using the [`items`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-items) config (as already pointed out in your question's comments):

```
var p = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
    renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
    title:'myPanel',
    items: [
        Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Click me!!!!',
            handler: function() {
                alert('You clicked the button!');
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

or - if you want to add the button **after** the component was already created - using the methods [`add`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-add) or [`insert`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-insert):

```
p.add(Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me!!!!',
    handler: function() {
        alert('You clicked the button!');
    }
}));
```

Useful documentation resources:

- [Layouts & containers](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/layouts_and_containers)
- [Components](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/components)